# Validating multiple checkboxes using jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to take a number of checkboxes and make sure at least one of these checkboxes is checked using jQuery validation. I haven't had any luck so far. What am I missing? I know my validation is there because it works for other fields, just not for my checkboxes. I put up the code on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stasis/ZDz59/), maybe this will help.

EDIT: I added brackets for my input name=list parameter (list[]). Also in my rules I changed the name parameter from list to 'list[]'. My old code is below. Thanks Sparky!

```
OLD: <input type='checkbox' name='list' id='fullProduct'></input>

FIXED: <input type='checkbox' name='list[]' id='fullProduct'></input>
```

Here is my code.

```
$("#tradeForm").validate({
        rules: {
            startDate: {
                required: true,
                date: true
            },
            endDate: {
                required: true,
                date: true
            },
            showName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            location: {
                required: true
            },
            list: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            startDate: "*",
            endDate: "*"
    }
});

                <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name of Show</th>
                    <td> <input type='text' name='showName'></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <td><input type='text' name='location'></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span style='padding-right: 50px;'>Select Literature</span></th>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='list' id='fullProduct'></input><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Guide One</span></td>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='list' id='oilProduct'></input><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Guide Two</span></td>
                </tr>                               
                <tr>                                
                    <td></td>                       
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='list' id='diamondProduct'></input><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Guide Three</span></td>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' name='list' id='motorProduct'></input><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Guide Four</span></td>
                </tr>                               
            </table>
```

Comment: The HTML code in your OP is not the same as the code in your jsFiddle, which is also the cause of your problem.  `name="list[]"` is not the same as `name="list"`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `name` of your checkbox group is `list[]`, not `list`, so you must declare the rule as such. [Since it contains brackets, `[]`, you must enclose it in quotes](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29):

```
rules: {
    'list[]': {
        required: true
    }
},
```

**Your jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZDz59/1/**

Comment: If your form consists of fields using names that aren't legal JavaScript identifiers, you have to quote those names when using the rules option:

Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @wowzuzz, Yes, I am referring to this:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29

Comment: To change the position of the validation label look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200659/custom-error-label-placement-using-jquery-validate-for-all-or-some-of-your-erro

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDz59/81/

Comment: @user2345998, what does your comment have to do with anything here?  The question is about an improperly declared rule, not message placement.  Please keep comments relevant.  Thanks.

Comment: First question after I read the answer was "how to change the position", and I tought it was nice to share a direct link to the solution. Of course I can delete it if you insist.

Comment: I know your intentions were good.  However, it's always best to keep comments relevant.  I appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: @kejo, 7 years ago has nothing to do with this:  you are not supposed to be asking any new questions within the comments section.  You're supposed to post a new question after doing an SO search.

Comment: Rudeness is not necessary. I will keep it more militaristic if that is how SO works then. So much for open, friendly learning.

Answer (score 2):

If you only intend one of the checkboxes to checked at all times, use **input type="radio"** instead.

If not: try change the name attribute of the checkboxes to **list[]**. As there can multiple checked values it must include the brackets to indicate it is an array. Otherwise the value will be overwritten.

Comment: I changed the names to list[] and no luck on my end. It just submits to my form action. It is validating my other fields though.

Comment: Try adding `minlength: 1` to the list rule.

Comment: You could add a click function to untick every box but the one you just clicked