# Checkboxes won't validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that I want to validate on the client side, and I'm using jQuery Validate for the task. Validation works with the other (input) fields, but not with the checkbox.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form name="insert_new_lesson" id="insert_new_lesson" method="post" action="" class="lesson-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input class="{category: true}" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="15" id="grade15">
    ... rest of the fields...


$("#insert_new_lesson").validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
        error.insertBefore(element);    
    },
    rules: {
        category: {
            required: 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked',
        },
        ...rest of the fields (validation works)
```

Comment: Are the brackets in the name a typeo?

Comment: From what you have posted you have set up a rule to make a field with name 'category' (not shown on your question) required as long as there is any checked checkbox in the form.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No, the brackets needs to be there to be able to collect which checkboxes the user has choose.

Comment: @politus: Yes, that's correct. It's enough if one checkbox is checked.

Comment: Where is your `input` named `category`?  Please show your complete `.validate()` and form HTML.  Also, explain in detail what "doesn't work" and exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('atLeastOne', function(value, element, param) {
    return $('input[name^="category"]').is(':checked');
}, 'Please select at least one checkbox');

$(function() {
    $("#insert_new_lesson").validate({rules: {
            'category[]': 'atLeastOne'
        }, groups: {
            checkboxes: 'category[]'
        }, errorPlacement: function(error, elem) {
            if (elem.attr('name').match(/category\[\]/)) {
                $('input[name^="category"]:last').next().after(error);
            }
            else {
                elem.next().after(error);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, that actually works. However, the error messages is put directly into the checkboxes, like this: http://i.imgur.com/vTWkySS.png. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I edited the answer, use elem.next() so that message comes after text of checkbox.

Comment: After changing the code they where moved a little bit to the right, but they still becomes input fields: http://i.imgur.com/FlBYv2V.png. Here's the full js code: http://pastie.org/private/anal4i57kfft6zvgucncpq if you wanna take a look (I actually have two groups of checkboxes, maybe that's the problem?). Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: First, show me html I don't know what's your HTML structure so can't sort out how to place error properly. Second, in atLeastOneYear rule, replace `return $('input[name^="category"]').is(':checked');` with `return $('input[name^="grade"]').is(':checked');`

Comment: Also, in errorPlacement use `if (elem.attr('name').match(/category\[\]/)) {
                $('input[name^="category"]:last').after(error);
            }

            else if (elem.attr('name').match(/grade\[\]/)) {
                $('input[name^="category"]:last').after(error);
            }
            else {
                elem.next().after(error);
                console.log(error);
            }`

Comment: Here's the full HTML code for the form. Of course I'll accept your answer. :) http://pastie.org/private/psrks56kkvhunw5cc8wq

Comment: Use `.parent().parent().append(error)` instead of `.next().after(error)` and it should solve your problem.

Comment: If you want error on new line do `.append("<br>" + error)` and it will appear on new line

Comment: Strangely enough.. no change. Thing is that I even tried to remove everything within else {  } and still the same result. Seems like it actually ignoring that else statement.

Comment: Strange... try `.parent().after(error)` instead of `.parent().parent().append(error)` and see if it works

Comment: Also, show me your code now, after modification. HTML and JS both

Comment: Same :/ Here's the updated JS: http://pastie.org/private/2runh4m1krrcjliyfibxcq. The HTML isn't changed so you can look at http://pastie.org/private/psrks56kkvhunw5cc8wq

Answer (score 1):

That a current problem with jQuery Validator. [See this issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/423) in the official repository.

As stated in one of the comments, you'll have to do the following to be able to validate fields with the same name:

```
$.validator.prototype.elements = function() {
    var validator = this;
    // select all valid inputs inside the form (no submit or reset buttons)
    return $(this.currentForm)
        .find(":input")
        .not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")
        .not( this.settings.ignore )
        .filter(function() {
            !this.name && validator.settings.debug && window.console && console.error( "%o has no name assigned", this);
            return validator.objectLength($(this).rules());
        });
};
```

Please note that I've modified the code from the comment in GitHub. The user dsand1234 used `find("input")`, which should be `find(":input")` in the line 5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried it but it's the same thing. Is it correct to set rules for "category" as done in my question (even if the name is category[])? Btw, should I put this before or after the "$("#insert_new_lesson").validate({..." code?

Comment: @dracula, where is the rest of your code?  Please edit your OP to show a more _complete_ example so people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this syntax for json (single quotes outside and double for key):

```
class='{"category": true}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and is a simple solution.  Just enclose the "name" in your rules with quotes.

```
rules: {
    'category[]': {
        required: true
    }
}
```

I found this solution on [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966465/validating-multiple-checkboxes-using-jquery-validation).