# jquery errorPlacement label position for single

Tags: jquery, validation, errorplacement

using: 
jquery validator

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div>
    <form id="everything">
        <label for="dd1">Select the best option</label>
        <br/>
        <select name="dd1" id="dd1" class="required">
            <option value="">None</option>
            <option value="o1">option 1</option>
            <option value="o2">option 2</option>
            <option value="o3">option 3</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for='agreement'>I accept the TOS</label>
        <input id="agreement" name="agreement" type="checkbox" style='float:left' />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to change the position of one of the error messages and leave the rest where they are.  I know you can use ErrorPlacement to achieve this but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to do it.

I've seen an example
[Custom Error Label Placement using jQuery validate (For all or some of your errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200659/custom-error-label-placement-using-jquery-validate-for-all-or-some-of-your-erro)

and created  http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3v5/215/

I want to adjust 
1.  change the color of "Accept the TOS" to 2E0854.
2.  move the error to 10px from the left.

what am I doing wrong?

thanks as always for the help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove/fix your **top - bottom margins**: http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3v5/219/

```
#everything label.error {
    color: #FB3A3A;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 60px; /* Top and Bottom to '0' */
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 320px;
}

#everything2 label.error {
    color: #2E0854;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px; /* Top and Bottom to '0' */
}
```

Additionally you have an extra `</div>` inside your `form`

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I guess in my haste to show an example I may have not been as clear in the intention.  I was more interested in changing the position and  of the "Accept the TOS" error only and was wondering how to go about doing that.  While leaving the "Please select an option" where it is.  thanks.